# Keep getting object of type 'closure' is not subsettable when I separate date and time

Tags: r, dplyr, error-code

I am new to R.
I am trying to separate date/ time into different columns.

The format within the column is 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM

[original format of the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlK4w.png)

I have tried it a few ways and nothing is working. Can someone explain where I am going wrong and how to fix it?

My first try:

```
sdo<- sleepday %>% separate(SleepDay,c("Date","Time"),sep=" ") %>% format (as.POSIXct(data$all),format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

My 2nd attempt:

When I tried to just use the following I didn't get the full date and time. The results were just separated by month and what I am assuming is the number of minutes:

```
sdo<- sleepday %>% separate(SleepDay,c("Date","Time")
```

[the results using code chunk above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iISmH.png)

Then I read up on it on a few sites and tried the following code chunk and received this message again:

```
Error in data$SleepDay : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> 


dt_sleep <- sleepday %>% format (as.POSIXct(data$SleepDay),format = "%H:%M:%S")


    

> 
> 
> dput(head(sleepday))
structure(list(Id = c(1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 
1503960366, 1503960366), SleepDay = c("4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", 
"4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/15/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/16/2016 12:00:00 AM", 
"4/17/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/19/2016 12:00:00 AM"), TotalSleepRecords = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 1), TotalMinutesAsleep = c(327, 384, 412, 340, 700, 
304), TotalTimeInBed = c(346, 407, 442, 367, 712, 320)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), SleepDay = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), TotalSleepRecords = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), TotalMinutesAsleep = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), TotalTimeInBed = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: (nil)>)
>
```

Comment: Please include code to generate your data (or data like it) and not a screenshot. It is ambiguous whether `SleepDay` is character data or datetime data when you show what it looks like on screen, and those situations would lead to different advice. Please include the output of `dput(sleepday)` or if that's too long, `dput(head(sleepday))` in the body of your question.

Comment: @JonSpring I'm not sure how to add or generate data on this site but I did add the dput(head(sleepday)) that you ask for. lowercase sleepday is the data frame and capitalized SleepDay is the column within the data frame that contains the date/time that needs to be separated.

Comment: The first part of your original attempt: `sleepday %>% separate(SleepDay,c("Date","Time"),sep=" ")` works just fine. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `format` bit though - you don't have a variable called `all` or a dataset called `data`. I suspect you want to do something like `sleepday %>%
  separate(SleepDay,c("Date","Time"),sep=" ") %>%
  mutate(out = format(Time, format="%H:%M:%S"))` though be careful that you've lost the AM/PM bit.

Comment: btw adding `extra = "merge"` after `sep=" "` will keep the AM/PM bit in your Time column.

Comment: Thank you guys so much that worked, I know this is not a class but I just want to understand why this part work @thelatemail  mutate(out = format(Time, format="%H:%M:%S"))  can you break it down for me. Unfortunately, this is how I learn. Thanks in advance guys if you are willing to do so and if not it's ok.

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you that helped, It would have been weird filtering all of that and not being able to determine whether not I'm looking at am or pm

Comment: The error comes from not being able to find a data object named `data` and the interpreter only finding the function named `data`. `SleepDay` column is not a datetime classed vector so you cannot use time functions with it.

Comment: Oh Ok! That makes sense @IRTFM Again Thanks you guys this helped a lot.

Comment: @thelatemail Where are you getting that version of`separate`?

Comment: @irtfm tidyr package I believe

Comment: @thelatemail So it's really just a tidyr version of `strsplit` with a named output? I formed the idea (incorrectly) that "Date" and "Time" were meaningful as input, but they're only new column names.

Answer (score 0):

You might get success with:

```
dt_sleep <- sleepday %>% mutate(SleepDay = as.POSIXct(SleepDay,
                               format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
   # now a date-time  (edit: now correctly deals with am/pm
   # and original guess was missing a closing parenthesis
dt_sleep$s_Date <- as.Date(dt_sleep$SleepDay ) #Date-classed column
dt_sleep$s_Time <- format(dt_sleep$SleepDay, "%I:%M:%S %p")  #character value


dt_sleep
# A tibble: 6 × 7
          Id SleepDay            TotalSleepRecords TotalMinutesAsleep TotalTimeInBed s_Date     s_Time     
       <dbl> <dttm>                          <dbl>              <dbl>          <dbl> <date>     <chr>      
1 1503960366 2016-04-12 00:00:00                 1                327            346 2016-04-12 12:00:00 AM
2 1503960366 2016-04-13 00:00:00                 2                384            407 2016-04-13 12:00:00 AM
3 1503960366 2016-04-15 00:00:00                 1                412            442 2016-04-15 12:00:00 AM
4 1503960366 2016-04-16 00:00:00                 2                340            367 2016-04-16 12:00:00 AM
5 1503960366 2016-04-17 00:00:00                 1                700            712 2016-04-17 12:00:00 AM
6 1503960366 2016-04-19 00:00:00                 1                304            320 2016-04-19 12:00:00 AM
```

I couldn't find a `separate` function that took "Date" and "Time" as arguments. There may be one, but I do have the tidyverse loaded. The `tidyr::separate` function says it uses regex patterns. You probably could put together a pair of regex patterns to separate your "MM/DD/YYYY H:M:S A/P"-formatted character values, but why not learn to use real tested code for managing datetime data?

Comment: Ok, I see. Will do! Thanks again! Appreciate your time.